# Cron job doesn't "unlink" files - why?

Tags: cron, file-exists, unlink

I have a php script that deletes a file from a specific folder on my server:

```
if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/folder/file1"))
{
unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/folder/file1");
}
```

When I go to this script address with my browser it works fine.

I created a cron job to run this script every hour and running this script from the cron job - the file is not deleted.

I also created a flag that send me an email and I suspect that the cron job gets a false response to the "file_exists" test and not continue to the "unlink" action.

Any idea why cron job wont delete the file?

Thanks

Anyone??

Comment: Is $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] set in a cron job?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean... Do I need to set this for the cron job to recognize the path of the file?

Comment: `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is a web server dependant variable. Have you checked that `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/folder/file1"` has the expected value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

Instead of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/folder/file1

Had to put this: /home/public_html/folder/file1